# Analytics - How to get how many users deleted % or number

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I cant find on analytics the quantity of users that installed my app and removed it.
Does Google play store statistics offers this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this answer from the developer console instead of google analytics. You can view how many current users are using your app and then you also have the total number of users(unique) who have installed your app. So the difference gives you what you want.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept the answer. And welcome.